# How to test the current instance name?

Tags: instance, verilog, system-verilog

I need to use the current instance name (full hierarchical name) in a generate if condition:

```
generate
   if (current_instance_name() == "a.b.c.foo")
   ...
```

Is there any way to do that in Verilog or SystemVerilog?
I know %m, but it only allows to print the instance name.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that. If you want a certain instance to contain different generated blocks, you'll have to use parameters and parameterize the instance accordingly.

Comment: Also, relying on full hierarchical paths inside a module is a very bad practice, because this breaks encapsulation.

Comment: The generate if condition requires a constant expression which can be evaluated during elaboration phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is

```
localparam string current_path = $sformatf("%m");

generate
if (current_path == "a.b.c.foo") begin ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use %m by passing it to $psprintf which will return a string. The following function should solve your problem:

```
function string current_instance_name();
return $psprintf("%m");
endfunction
```

Comment: While this does return the full path, I'm pretty sure he can't use it in a generate statement, because it doesn't resolve to an elaborate time constant.

Comment: Although the major simulator support `$psprintf` it is not part of the IEEE1364(Verilog) or IEEE1800(SystemVerilog) standards. To be complaint with the standard(s), use `$sformatf`

Comment: "%m" returns the current path where the format string locates, not the instance name. If you place the function in a package, and call the function inside your module/instance, the format string results in "package_name::current_instance_name"

Comment: @jclin, ha, ok that's also so true. It will return function location and function name.

Comment: Instead of "%m", in VCS there is "%i" that will return string indicating from which instance/block the function was called.